# Italicising "et al" in inline citiations in Rmarkdown

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm producing a report in `Rmarkdown` but 'et al' in the short form of the author list is not getting italicised in inline citations. Italicisation does occur in normal citations.

Here is some `Rmarkdown` to illustrate:

```
---
title: "testCite"
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
csl: the-plant-journal.csl
bibliography: test.bib
---

The fly *Drosophila melanogaster* is one of the most intensively studied organisms in biology [@Adams:2000tj].

According to @Adams:2000tj, the fly *Drosophila melanogaster* is one of the most intensively studied organisms in biology.
```

This gets me the following page:

[image: testCite.html]

Looking in the `html` I can see the `<em>` tags are not being added to the inline citation:

```
<p>The fly <em>Drosophila melanogaster</em> is one of the most intensively studied organisms in biology <span class="citation">(Adams <em>et al.</em>, 2000)</span>.</p>
<p>According to <span class="citation">Adams et al. (2000)</span>, the fly <em>Drosophila melanogaster</em> is one of the most intensively studied organisms in biology.</p>
```

`the-plant-journal.csl` was downloaded [from the repository](http://www.zotero.org/styles/the-plant-journal). Here are the contents of `test.bib`:

```
@article{Adams:2000tj,
author = {Adams, MD and Celniker, SE and Holt, RA and Evans, CA and Gocayne, JD and Amanatides, PG and Scherer, SE and Li, PW and Hoskins, RA and Galle, RF and George, RA and Lewis, SE and Richards, S and Ashburner, M and Henderson, SN and Sutton, GG and Wortman, JR},
title = {{The genome sequence of \emph{Drosophila melanogaster}}},
journal = {Science},
year = {2000},
volume = {287},
number = {5461},
pages = {2185--2195},
affiliation = {Celera Genom, Rockville, MD 20850 USA},
language = {English},
read = {Yes},
rating = {0},
date-added = {2012-03-02T23:35:05GMT},
date-modified = {2015-07-28T15:38:34GMT},
abstract = {The fly Drosophila melanogaster is one of the most intensively studied organisms in biology...},
url = {http://www.sciencemag.org/content/287/5461/2185.short}
}
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm using `Rstudio 0.99.473` which is calling `pandoc 1.13.1` and `pandoc-citeproc 0.5`. SessionInfo at the end. I hope that is all the necessary information!

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] htmltools_0.2.6 tools_3.2.2     yaml_2.1.13     rmarkdown_0.8   digest_0.6.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed when I updated to `pandoc-citeproc 0.9`.